# WCF-RIA: Access Denied after 2nd function call

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

I have a Web Application that uses Silverlight and WCF RIA. The application also uses Forms authentication and HTTP. 
The Silverlight application makes calls to a DomainService with multiple Public functions within it. At the top of the Domain class are the attributes:

> [RequiresAuthentication]
>   [EnableClientAccess()]

This application and DomainService has operated just fine for a long time but all of a sudden (and on multiple test machines) we began getting the error:

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:
>   Load operation failed for query 'MyFunction'. Access to operation
>   'MyFunction' was denied.

The thing is, this only happens on the 2nd and any subsequent calls into this service. For example, if from my Silverlight app I call FunctionA() first that will work fine and the property in the service function

> this.ServiceContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

returns True. But if I then call a second function in the service I get the error. If I put a breakpoint in the second function it will never get hit.

If I comment out the attribute [RequiresAuthentication] then it all works again. For security, I need the user to be authenticated. When I return to a regular aspx page and check authentication the user is still authenticated.

I have checked every possible configuration option I know of and can not track this issue down. The fact that it works on the first call but then always fails with the access error on every other call is puzzling.

In the service I overrode the Initialize function so that I can check the Identity property and see if the user is authenticated. For the first call

> context.User.Identity.Name

has a value and

> IsAuthenticated == true.

As I mentioned before, the first function I call in the service will succeed now, but the second function I call in the service context.User.Identity.Name will be an empty string and IsAuthenticated will be false.

The thing is, I know the user is still authenticated on the website because if I reload the Silverlight page and call that service again the first function call see's me as authenticated and then the second one does not - once again. Also, if I go back to a regular non-Silverlight aspx page I am still authenticated.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. Another programmer added the below line recently to app.xaml.cs.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

I commented out the line and all is well again and I can require authentication on my domain service.